# Prove $T\Omega \times T x=T(\Omega \times x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, index-notation

Let $T:V\to V, T\in SO(3)$ represent a rotation matrix in $\mathbb R^3$, $\Omega \in \mathbb R^3$ is a vector, and $x\in \mathbb R^3$ also represent a vector. How to prove $T\Omega \times T x=T(\Omega \times x)$ by **use of index notations**?

**My Attempt:** Since $T\in SO(3)$, $TT^T=T^TT=1$, and we can write this as ${T^{a}}_{b}{T_{c}}^b={\delta^a}_c$. The desired result can be written as:
$$
{\varepsilon^{a}}_{bc}{T^b}_d\Omega^d {T^{c}}_e x^e={T^{a}}_{b}{\varepsilon^b}_{de}\Omega^dx^e
$$
But I have no idea how to make use of $TT^T=T^TT=1$ to get the desired result. Could anyone please help me? If I've made mistakes, please also remind me.

Comment: This is one way to do it; multiply both sides with $T_{ak}$ and use the identities $\varepsilon_{mbc}T^m_{\,\,\,\,k}T^b_{\,\,\,d}T^c_{\,\,\,e}=\det(T)\varepsilon_{kde}=\varepsilon_{kde}$ and $T_{ak}T^{am}=\delta^m_k$

Comment: I don't quite understand where $\varepsilon_{mbc}T^m_{\,\,\,\,k}$ comes from. Could you please expand the details?

Comment: $\varepsilon^a_{\,\,bc}=g^{am}\varepsilon_{mbc}$ and $T_{ak}g^{am}=T^m_{\,\,k}$

Comment: I see, and how to deal with the right part?

Comment: If you mean the right hand side, use the same trick; $\varepsilon^b_{\,\,de}=g^{mb}\varepsilon_{mde}$ and $T_{ak}g^{mb}T^a_{\,\,\,b}=T_{ak}T^{am}=\delta^m_k$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a nice trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the techniques [@ContraKinta](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/588314/contrakinta) said in the comments, we are able to solve the problem.

Since we are going to prove
$$
{\varepsilon^{a}}_{bc}{T^b}_d\Omega^d {T^{c}}_e x^e={T^{a}}_{b}{\varepsilon^b}_{de}\Omega^dx^e
$$
Cancelling out $\Omega^d x^e$ on both sides, it is sufficient to prove
$$
{\varepsilon^{a}}_{bc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e ={T^{a}}_{b}{\varepsilon^b}_{de}
$$
Multiplying both sides with $T_{ak}$, and now the task is to prove
$$
{\varepsilon^{a}}_{bc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e T_{ak} ={T^{a}}_{b}{\varepsilon^b}_{de} T_{ak}
$$
For the left side of the equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\varepsilon^{a}}_{bc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e T_{ak} &= g^{am} \varepsilon_{mbc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e T_{ak} \\
&=g^{am}  T_{ak}  \varepsilon_{mbc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e \\
&={T^m}_k\varepsilon_{mbc}{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e \\
&=\varepsilon_{mbc}{T^m}_k{T^b}_d {T^{c}}_e \\
&=\det T \varepsilon_{kde} \\
&=\varepsilon_{kde}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the right part of the equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{T^{a}}_{b}{\varepsilon^b}_{de} T_{ak} &= {T^{a}}_{b} g^{mb} \varepsilon_{mde} \\
&= T^{am} \varepsilon_{mde} T_{ak}\\
&= T^{am} T_{ak} \varepsilon_{mde} \\
&= g^{mi} {T^{a}}_i g_{kj}{T_a}^j  \varepsilon_{mde}\\
&= {T^{a}}_i {T_a}^j \varepsilon_{mde}\\
&= g^{mi} g_{kj}{\delta_i}^j\varepsilon_{mde} \\
&= {\delta ^m}_k \varepsilon_{mde} \\
&= \varepsilon_{kde}\\
&= \text{left side}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, we proved that the left and right sides are equal, which is equivalent to prove the desired equation.

Comment: Nice! Just a few comments. Since $TT^T=T^TT$ you can actually use $T^{am}T_{ak}=\delta^m_k$ directly. Also be careful with the words "cancelling", you are not allowed to divide both sides by $\Omega^dx^e$, but of course you are allowed to just consider only part of the equation at any time. Finally another maybe more elegant way show this is to rename the index $a$ to $k$ on the LHS and multiply this side with the identity $T^a_{\,\,v}T_k^{\,\,\,v}=\delta^a_k$ (renaming the index back to $a$ again, keeping LHS the same). This way you are only manipulating the LHS.